# Fastest sum over margins in N-dimensional array: apply(X, MARGIN=c(1,2), sum)

Tags: r, rcpp

I have a 4-dimensional array and I need to compute the sum over two of its dimensions. I see that `apply` is surprisingly slow.

I have tried the `compiler` library, but speed barely improves:

```
library(compiler)

X <- array(2, dim=c(1000,20,10,125))

suma <- function(X){
  apply(X, MARGIN=c(1,2), sum)
}

suma.cmp <- cmpfun(suma)

benchmark(suma.cmp(X), suma(X), replications = 50)

#       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child
#1 suma.cmp(X)           50  24.616    1.000    24.164    0.424          0
#2     suma(X)           50  24.892    1.011    24.440    0.416          0
```

I would give Rcpp a try, but `RcppArmadillo` has no 4-dimensional arrays as far as I know.

How can I make this computation (`apply(X, MARGIN=c(1,2), sum)`) as fast as possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`rowSums` is about 15x faster. It pretty quickly goes to C, so I think it will be difficult to improve on it.

```
microbenchmark(
  apply = suma(X),
  rowsum = rowSums(X, dims = 2),
  times = 10
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#    expr       min        lq      mean    median        uq       max neval cld
#   apply 692.14893 818.67450 828.66410 829.47926 874.23754 885.36019    10   b
#  rowsum  48.39865  49.85822  51.37486  51.09379  52.04339  56.29224    10  a 

identical(rowSums(X, dims = 2), suma(X))
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks @Gregor. Can we sum over non-contiguous dimensions? `apply(X, MARGIN=c(1,3), sum)`

Comment: No. See the documentation in `?rowSums`: *"dims: For row\*, the sum or mean is over dimensions dims+1, ...; for col\* it is over dimensions 1:dims."* You **can** use `aperm` to permute the dimensions, making whatever dimensions you want to sum over contiguous.